# Button element not aligning properly on a different computer

Tags: html, css

So I have a button that turns on dark mode. I aligned it manually because if I use:

```
align:left
```

it doesn't completely align to the left. So instead I used this:

```
right: 1450px;
position: absolute;
```

However, if I view this page on a different computer (one with a bigger screen) this button appears as if I'm using align:left.
Here is my complete code:
Html:

```
<button class="DefaultButton Mode" id="DarkMode" onclick="DarkMode()">
Dark Mode
</button>
```

CSS:

```
#DarkMode {
  background-color: Orange;
  color: white;
  right: 1450px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

(Note: In the html, the class and the DarkMode() function *don't matter*).
Full code [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/scorekeepr):
If the link is not working, the web address is here:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/scorekeepr.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the parent div a flexbox, flexbox allows easy vertical and horizontal positioning.

```
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
```

Maybe you should open dev tools in your browser and see what are the default browser settings, because they are different and usually cause such problems. See what CSS browser adds to your code, maybe it breaks the layout.

Also dont use absolute, it takes elements out of the flow and causes problems when you view the page on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a button on the left side try ***left: 0***